# SharePoint 2013 Public site how to test SQL Injection attacks vulnerability

Tags: 2013, security

Hi In SharePoint 2013 Public site how to test SQL Injection attacks ? In SharePoint 2013 web application i deployed some custom web parts,displaying data from custom lists to pages etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharePoint codebase has protections for SQL injection attacks. There isn't anything you would need to explicitly test.

Comment: Hi Trevor Is CAMAL Queries written in side farm solutions does make any problem, for example there is contact pages and user input forms available for users to save data in custom list

Comment: No, because those CAML queries are validated by SharePoint code.